# Adding Up dynamic data in a table not working jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I bring my data back from my database in json format. as you can see i add them to the table. On each pass i pass the newly created table row to the calculate sum which works as all the details are alerted there. Problem is the total is not updating even though in the sum it can be echo'ed.

```
function calculateRow(list) {
    var cost = 0;
    var $row = $(list).closest("tr");
    var weeks = parseFloat($row.find('.weeks').val());
    var quantity = parseFloat($row.find('.quantity').val());
    var price = parseFloat($row.find('.price').val());
    var mark = parseFloat($row.find('.mark').val());
    var ptype = $row.find('.ptype').val();
//alerts me of numbers here
alert('-'+weeks +'-'+quantity+'-'+price+'-'+mark+'-'+ptype);
        var mcond = weeks * quantity * price;
        $row.find('.total').val(mcond.toFixed(2));
        $row.find('.total-prod').val(mcond.toFixed(2));
//alerts me of total 
        alert(mcond);
}
```

Now my script for the new rows

```
function editquote(){
        var list = "";
        $.getJSON('responder.php?method=edit-quote',function(data){
        $.each(data.products,function(index,item){
            list += '<tr class="copyIng"><td class="title"><select size="1" class="equip" name="item[]"  data-mini="true"><option value="'+item.pid+'">'+item.pname+'</option></select></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text"  style="text-align: center;" class="weeks" name="weeks[]" value="'+item.pw+'" /></center><input type="hidden"  class="mark" name="mark[]" value="'+item.pmu+'" /><input type="hidden" class="ptype" name="ptype[]" value="'+item.pt+'" /></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class ="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="'+item.pq+'" /></center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class ="price" name="price[]"  class="price" value="'+item.pc+'" /></center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);"><center>'+
            '<input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class="total" name="total" value="0.00"  readonly="true" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm1" class="total-prod" value="0.00" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm2" class="total-trans" value="0.00" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm3" class="total-lab" value="0.00" />'+
            '</center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><a class="remove"><img src="red.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a></center></td></tr>';
            $("#equipTable tr.grandtotal").before(list);
            $(".copyIng").trigger("create");
            calculateRow(list);
            $( "#equipTable" ).table( "refresh" );
            list ='';
        });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't there is a reason to use `closest("tr")` since `tr` is part of the `list`. You can do `$(list).find(element);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
var $row = $(list).closest("tr");
```

To this:

```
var $row = $(list).siblings("tr").last();
```

as `.closest()` traverses up the DOM, but in your case you want breadth rather than depth.  I included the `.last()` method because I'm assuming you want to update the last row, the last `<tr>`. If that is not the case, let me know and I can adjust my answer accordingly.

**EDIT**

Change to `editquote()` this (I just added 1 line):

```
function editquote(){
        var list = "";
        $.getJSON('responder.php?method=edit-quote',function(data){
        $.each(data.products,function(index,item){
            list += '<tr class="copyIng"><td class="title"><select size="1" class="equip" name="item[]"  data-mini="true"><option value="'+item.pid+'">'+item.pname+'</option></select></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text"  style="text-align: center;" class="weeks" name="weeks[]" value="'+item.pw+'" /></center><input type="hidden"  class="mark" name="mark[]" value="'+item.pmu+'" /><input type="hidden" class="ptype" name="ptype[]" value="'+item.pt+'" /></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class ="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="'+item.pq+'" /></center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class ="price" name="price[]"  class="price" value="'+item.pc+'" /></center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);"><center>'+
            '<input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class="total" name="total" value="0.00"  readonly="true" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm1" class="total-prod" value="0.00" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm2" class="total-trans" value="0.00" />'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="dm3" class="total-lab" value="0.00" />'+
            '</center></td>'+
            '<td class="smallrow"><center><a class="remove"><img src="red.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></a></center></td></tr>';
            //NEW LINE
            list = $(list);
            $("#equipTable tr.grandtotal").before(list);
            $(".copyIng").trigger("create");
            calculateRow(list);
            $( "#equipTable" ).table( "refresh" );
            list ='';
        });
        });
    }
```

And then change `var $row` to this:

```
var $row = list;
```

The issue was that `list` was a string, so when you passed it into `calculateRow()`, `$row` became a new element, rather than a reference to the element inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Each row has a sum total. Everytime the each statement is passed i delete the one before so i can get the new tr for the total. ill try and get a jsfiddle sorted as an exampl

Comment: Gotcha, I see the line now. In that case just do this: `$row = $(list);` as the `list` is only the most recent row

Comment: yes row list does work and it does alert the sums but it still doesn't update my .total class of the row. It does the sums just doesnt update.

Comment: affraid not. i have a partial fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dodgeyguy/ahe1aurg/  this may give u an idea whats not working. on my form it all works but the total box for each field does not add up

Comment: Yeah, so applying the edit I made it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ahe1aurg/3/